# Find the inverse of $L$ given $g(x) = \int^x_0 -\frac{x}{(a-y)^2} f(y) dy$ and $(Lf)(x) = g(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, inverse, integral-equations

I am working on something else, but this is a point that I do not know how to do. $g(x) = \int^x_0 -\frac{x}{(a-y)^2} f(y) dy$ given $(Lf)(x) = g(x)$. How should I approach finding the inverse $L^{-1}$ in this case.

I tried differentiate both sides and got:
$$g'(x) = -\frac{x}{(a-x)^2}f(x) + \int^x_0 -\frac{1}{(a-y)^2}f(y)dy$$
Then I used $g(x)/x = \int^x_0 -\frac{1}{(a-y)^2}f(y)dy$ and replace it back in to get a differential equation, which led me nowhere.

How should I start solving for $L^{-1}$ or does it even exist?

Comment: Does $Lf$ means composition or pointwise multiplication?

Comment: L represents the operation that turns $f$ into $g$.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, you can differentiate $g(x)/x$ to find $f$ in function of $x,g, g^{\prime}$.

Comment: That is a really good point. I'm trying it out right now.

Comment: @Kelenner Do you see a way to replace $g'$ with something else?

Comment: Can you be more precise on what do you want  ?

Comment: Using your suggestion, I got $L^{-1}g = (a-x)^2/x^2 g(x) - (a-x)^2/x g'(x)$. I am looking for a way to make this completely dependent on x and g only. Actually, I think I got it. Thank you so much.